# Is better to use Hiera or basic node definition?

Tags: puppet, hiera

Which is better for Puppet 3.7 or newer ?

1- Hiera with Yaml definition as

> ubuntu.yaml:

```
---
classes:
  - google-chrome
  - xcode
```

2- Base node definition as

> node.pp:

```
node "ubuntu" {
   include google-chrome
   include xcode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand purpose of using hiera. According to [documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/):

> Hiera is a key/value lookup tool for configuration data, built to make Puppet better and let you set node-specific data without repeating yourself.

Hiera gives you a versatile way to deliver configuration parameters. So in my opinion "2- Base node definition", with hiera as configuration provider is proper way of using puppet with hiera.

E.g: instead of definig:

```
node node1 {
   class { 'some_class_1' :
     param_1 => value1,
     param_2 => value2,
   }

   class { 'some_class_2' :
     param_1 => value3,
     param_2 => value4,
   }
}

node node2 {
   class { 'some_class_1' :
     param_1 => value11,
     param_2 => value22,
   }

   class { 'some_class_2' :
     param_1 => value33,
     param_2 => value44,
   }
}
```

Use hiera as configuration provider. In puppet define only:

```
node some_regexp { #or just provide node names
   include some_class_1
   include some_class_2
}
```

than define proper hiera files:

> node1.yaml

```
some_class_1::param_1: value1
some_class_1::param_2: value2
some_class_2::param_1: value3
some_class_2::param_2: value4
```

> node2.yaml

```
some_class_1::param_1: value11
some_class_1::param_2: value22
some_class_2::param_1: value33
some_class_2::param_2: value44
```

Comment: Yes but Hiera is not only for parameters, you can specify some classes by node. Isn't it?